# Accessing environment/system varilable in spring when application is deployed on tomcat7

Tags: spring, deployment, tomcat7, environment

My war file has 3 properties files: test.properties, dev.properties and prod.properties.

My application context has the following

> ```
> <bean id="local" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
>       <property name="locations">
>         <list><value>classpath:${env}.properties</value></list>
>       </property>
>       <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
>       <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
>       <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
>   </bean>
> ```

I have done the following

1. set the following in tomcat7/conf/web.xml

   > ```
   > <env-entry>
   > <env-entry-name>env</env-entry-name>
   > <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
   > <env-entry-value>dev</env-entry-value>
   > ```
2. set the following in tomcat7/conf/context.xml

   > ```
   > <Environment name="env" value="dev" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
   > ```
3. set CATALINA_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS

   > ```
   > echo $CATALINA_OPTS  =   -Denv=dev
   > echo $JAVA_OPTS  =       -Denv=dev
   > ```

I start tomcat using the command, sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start

This does not load any of my variables. I still get

> ```
> Invalid bean definition with name 'local' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'env'
> ```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by setting the variables in catalina.properties in tomcat7/conf

env = dev

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Spring 3.1 and use Bean Profiles.